# How to get the Search box to the left end using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS. I want to know how can I make the Search box to move towards the far left along with the search button. I don't want the Home, profile, settings to move towards right.

Below is the code.Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My first css program</title>

<style>

nav{
text-align:right;
list-style:none;
border:none;
border-color:white;
background-color:none;
padding:none;
margin:none;
}

li{
color:green;
background-color:pink;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
padding-right:10px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<nav>
<li>

<input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search" padding-left:none>

<a href="www.az.com">Home |</a>
<a href="www.az.com/profile">Profile |</a>
<a href="www.az.com/settings">Settings</a>
</li>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Don't use `li` elements wihtout a `ul` parent. Put all these elements together into a `ul` and put them into seperate `li` s. Then you can assign `display: flex` to the `ul` and `margin-right: auto;` to the first `li` to align it left, while the rest is moved to the right:

```css
nav {
  text-align: right;
  list-style: none;
  border: none;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: none;
  padding: none;
  margin: none;
}

.x {
  list-style: none;
  color: green;
  background-color: pink;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
}
.x li {
margin-right: 1em;
}
.x li:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="x">
    <li>
      <input type="text" name="search">
      <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" padding-left:none>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="www.az.com">Home |</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="www.az.com/profile">Profile |</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="www.az.com/settings">Settings</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed including style property.

```
<input type="text" name="search" style="padding-left:none">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search" style="padding-left:none">
```

OR this way:

```
<input type="text" name="search" style="float:left;">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search" style="float:left;">
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. Use float left to move it towards left.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My first css program</title>

<style>

nav{
text-align:right;
list-style:none;
border:none;
border-color:white;
background-color:none;
padding:none;
margin:none;
}

li{
color:green;
background-color:pink;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
padding-right:10px;
}
.left{
float:left;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<nav>
<li>
<div class="left">
<input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search" >
</div>
<a href="www.az.com">Home |</a>
<a href="www.az.com/profile">Profile |</a>
<a href="www.az.com/settings">Settings</a>
</li>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My first css program</title>

<style>

nav{
text-align:right;
list-style:none;
border:none;
border-color:white;
background-color:none;
padding:none;
margin:none;
}

li{
color:green;
background-color:pink;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
padding-right:10px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<nav>
<li>

<input type="text" name="search" style="float:left">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search" style="float:left">

<a href="www.az.com">Home |</a>
<a href="www.az.com/profile">Profile |</a>
<a href="www.az.com/settings">Settings</a>
</li>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```